# The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am having trouble implementing ASPNetIdentity on my MVC project
I am getting this error in the var line (The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context.):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using EZ.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

namespace EZ.Controllers
{
public class RoleController : Controller
{
    ApplicationDbContext context;

    public RoleController()
    {
        context = new ApplicationDbContext(); 
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Get All Roles
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var roles = context.Roles.ToList();
        return View(roles);
    } 

    /// <summary>
    /// Create  a New role
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
   // GET: /Roles/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Roles/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            context.Roles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole()
            {
                Name = collection["RoleName"]
            });
            context.SaveChanges();
            ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully !";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    } 

    /// <summary>
    /// Set Role for Users
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ActionResult SetRoleToUser()
    {
        var list = context.Roles.OrderBy(role => role.Name).ToList().Select(role => new SelectListItem { Value = role.Name.ToString(), Text = role.Name }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Roles = list;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult UserAddToRole(string uname, string rolename)
    {
        ApplicationUser user = context.Users.Where(usr => usr.UserName.Equals(uname, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();

        // Display All Roles in DropDown

        var list = context.Roles.OrderBy(role => role.Name).ToList().Select(role => new SelectListItem { Value = role.Name.ToString(), Text = role.Name }).ToList();
        ViewBag.Roles = list;

        if (user != null)
        {
            var account = new AccountController();
            account.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, rolename);

            ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully !";

            return View("SetRoleToUser");
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Sorry user is not available";
            return View("SetRoleToUser");
        }

    }
}
```

}

I have scripted the tables in my DB.

This is the exact same code as in the role-security-mvc5-master project from CodeProject.com. The only difference is that I moved the tables in my DB ana dI changed the connection string. What is the piece I am missing?

in my IdentityModel.cs I have:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

If you need more code, please let me know and I will post.

Comment: When the project was created, identity, a database at locadb. when I moved the tables in my DB I overwrote the entire Default connection string with the one I created for E. The big probelm here was that the default connection needs providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> and NOT providerName="System.Data.EntityClient". Be careful there. Credit needs to go to this excellent article from Daniel Eagle: http://danieleagle.com/blog/2014/05/setting-up-asp-net-identity-framework-2-0-with-database-first-vs2013-update-2-spa-template/. Tons of detail on how to use Identity with DB first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the project was created, identity, a database at locadb. when I moved the tables in my DB I overwrote the entire Default connection string with the one I created for E. The big probelm here was that the default connection needs providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> and NOT providerName="System.Data.EntityClient". Be careful there. Credit needs to go to this excellent article from Daniel Eagle: http://danieleagle.com/blog/2014/05/setting-up-asp-net-identity-framework-2-0-with-database-first-vs2013-update-2-spa-template/. Tons of detail on how to use Identity with DB first.